# How can I tell where I am on my daily quota?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, quota

Going here: https://script.google.com/dashboard , I can see the quotas listed per API.  I recently hit a limit using the following function inside the script panel of a google sheet:

```
function getLastEmail_(entry) {
  var email = entry[0];
  if (email) {
    var emails = [];
    var emails = GmailApp.search(email).map(function (email) {
      return getFormattedDate_(email.getLastMessageDate());
    }).sort();
    return (emails.length) ? [emails.pop()] : [""];
  }
  return [""];
}
```

My goal is to determine the last date of contact for an email address in a google sheet.  There are 5k entries in the sheet, so I prefer to do this via script.  After my testing, I got to about 380 or so lines when I got an error msg of `Service invoked too many times for one day: gmail. (line 83, file "get_last_visit")`.  I don't see how I used 50k calls (the limit for a gsuite business account) and I can't find any usage reporting metrics anywhere.

Is there a way to:

A) increase or work-around the limit for an individual user either via subscription, payment option, unbound script, etc
B) monitor the usage as it's happening to prevent unintended calls to the API that are running over the limit.

EDIT:
From https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?project=project-id-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx I am seeing "This project has no resources" under the "Resources" content block.

Comment: If you use the rest API (advanced service Gmail) then you can monitor its quota.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google intends to offer a "Flexible" plan that may allow for extension of quotas but that's currently in beta.

As for monitoring API usage you can do that via the api console. First you need to open the GCP project associated with your script by navigating to **`Resources > Cloud Platform Project`** from the Apps Script IDE. Then open the API Console for your GCP project by clicking the project id (the blue text).

From the console open the hamburger menu (by clicking the icon made of 3 horizontal bars in the top-left corner) and navigate to API dashboard via **`API & Services > dashboard`**. Select the GMail API from the list of APIs and then select the quotas tab.

The quotas tab should look like the following:

[image]

Clicking the download icon to the top-right of the bar-chart will download a CSV with usage metrics.

You should also check Google's API Explorer, there might be a REST API available that allows you to fetch quota information.

Comment: Does this include bound script usage?  I'm using the script from a google sheet and I haven't been able to see any api usage. Bumped you up because this is helpful, just not sure it's an answer yet due to the type of script it is.

Comment: Made an edit to reflect the "This project has no resources" status

Comment: @Shane This answer applies to your use of APIs enabled in the Google Cloud Project. Native Apps Script services like Gmail Service (`GmailApp`) are not tracked here - only the advanced service (using `Gmail`).

Comment: @tehhowch if they are subject to quotas, is their usage tracked/displayed somewhere I can monitor?

Comment: @Shane no. Some services (like MailApp) allow you to perform a quota check, but in general you as a developer are expected to write a robust application that handles quota errors (e.g. by using exponential backoff, etc.) For some users, there are trial programs that use a [flexible quota system.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#flexible_quotas_early_access)

Comment: I'll look into exponential backoff...  Never heard of it until just now, but it looks incredibly useful at first glance.  Will dive deeper into quota error handling, thanks.

Comment: Hey Dimu, would you mind trying to answer [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52542789/check-specific-user-account-quota-usage-for-gmail-api). I'd like a similar solution, but with data per user account. I have many gmail accounts in my organization, I'd like to check quota usage for specific users.