# Check specific user account quota usage for Gmail API

Tags: c#, gmail-api

I'm using Gmail API .NET client to send/get emails.

Recently I started getting exceptions with this message for some gmail accounts, for both sending/getting emails:

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
User-rate limit exceeded.  Retry after 2018-09-25T13:31:30.444Z [429]
Errors [
    Message[User-rate limit exceeded.  Retry after 2018-09-25T13:31:30.444Z] Location[ - ] Reason[rateLimitExceeded] Domain[usageLimits]
]
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to check a per-user quota usage for my project for a specific account, in the console I found this:

[image: Console Quota]

> In the **Queries per 100 seconds per user** there are no numbers, and the hint from the question mark icon just says: *Per user quota usage is not displayed.*

From [Gmail API Docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota#top_of_page) we can find :

- Per User-rate limit: 250 quota units per user per second, moving average (allows short bursts)
- `messages.send` method consumes 100 quota units
- `messages.get` method consumes 5 quota units
- `messages.list` method consumes 5 quota units
- `messages.attachments.get` method consumes 5 quota units

I don't think I'm reaching 250 quota units per second for any user, yet I'd like to make sure and check that on Google Console for a specific user account. Is that possible?

I've heard of exponential backoff, which is suitable if you indeed make many calls. In my case, I shouldn't be making many calls, so I'd like to investigate that and fix, rather than just implementing a backoff.

Answer (score 0):

The console doesn't say the per-user quota usage because it is different for every user - it doesn't make sense to list every single user's quota usage.

Exponential back-off is recommended. Not only does it allow your usage to be throttled to the rate limit, but it also is the correct way to handle server-side errors.

Comment: Hey, thanks for trying to help me. I wasn't expecting that screen to show the per-user quota precisely because of what you said, it wouldn't make sense. I just added that in case anyone wondered, but I was expecting to find somewhere I could select one of the user accounts in my organization and see their quota usage. Exponential backoff is recommended if you are querying close to the limits, which shouldn't be my case. I don't want to just implement, rely on it and forget, I suspect my app might be misbehaving, because it shouldn't be making so many calls.